# Where to put the LICENSE file in a Symfony application?

Tags: symfony, licensing

I have a web application made with Symfony2 and I want to add my license choice in the repository. The thing is that the default Symfony2 project has a LICENSE file in the root directory and I don't know where I am supposed to put my LICENSE file and if I should delete the Symfony2's one. Also happens with README file.

I guess that you Symfony2 programmers sure know how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Your own application code should be located mostly in the `src` folder. If you take a look at [some Bundles](https://github.com/symfony) or other components of *Symfony2* you can see that they all have a separate `LICENSE` file in their bundle root directory. So the correct choice for your file would be:

```
src/.../.../LICENSE
```

In this case your `LICENSE` file would also be included if you install your bundle via composer on a different project. In that case it would be at:

```
vendor/.../.../LICENSE
```

Comment: But my application is not just a bundle. It is a WEB application and some files are located at `app/Resources` directory.

Comment: Maybe the correct place for a non bundled app is the `app` directory itself: is there where you put all the files related to the applications, as the PHPUnit config files, other configurations and all the stuff that pertins to your application.